# Xamarin Hot Reload doesn't make design changes to live data

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, hot-reload

When I make a change, such as a text color to XAML, in this case a label, during Hot Reload/Debug,
the label's text is disappeared. (Or) It doesn't reassign the label.

It seems Hot Reload doesn't make changes to the design of data assigned at runtime or compiled time.

Is there anyway to fix it? or Does Xamarin Hot Reload has a missing feature?

```
<Label x:Name="label1" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Blue"/>
```

```
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     label1.Text = "Label 1";
}
```

Comment: Did you set linking to "None" in android options?

Comment: Do you mean the setting in Android>Option>Build>Android Build>Linker>Linker Behavior>"Don't Link" ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Comment: and also enable mono shared runtime and Fast deployment. Clean rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Please update for VS version to 16.7 or later, I test it in the 16.6.0 it not work, but it could be work in the VS version to 16.7. or later

And set reload option like following screenshot

[image]

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: So I am on Mac VS version 8.7.3 (build 13). I updated the XF to 4.8.0.1269 to all projects. When I try that with "Changes Only," it doesn't even refresh Hot Reload on XAML. It reload with "Entire Page." But with either options, the label's text I assign in C# doesn't make any changes. I was deploying my app via WiFi. So I change it with USB cable. It's still doesn't make changes. Especially the Hot Reload's 2nd option doesn't make changes even on XAML (on Mac VS version).

Comment: i see. i submitted an issue on Xamarin's Github. Thanks for your input. :)

Comment: Could you share a github link to this comment? If DU have solution to fix this issue in VS for mac, others(have same issue) can see it.

Comment: yes...
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11845